# R shiny variable graphs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a dataframe with multiple data types. I want to change graph type whenever the input in the shiny app changes in the sidebar panel. The condition I am trying to satisfy are

1. If 2 numerical variables are selected plot a scatter plot
2. if one categorical and one numerical variable is selected plot a boxplot
3. if two categorical variables are selected plot a barplot

The code I have tried till now

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)


df  <- read_table("cars.xls")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Car Dataset Analysis"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("X_variable", "X Variable:", 
                  c("No of Cylinders" = "Cylinders",
                    "Type of car" = "Type",
                    "Engine Size" = "EngineSize",
                    "Fuel Tank capacity" = "Fuel.tank.capacity",
                    "Origin of the car"="Origin",
                    "Prices"="Price",
                    "Rev /min"="RPM",
                    "Weight of car"="Weight",
                    "MPG city"="MPG.city",
                    "Horsepower of car"="HorsePower",
                    "Passengers capacity"="Passengers",
                    "Length of car"="Length",
                    "Manufacturer of car"="Manufacturer",
                    "Model of car"="Model" )),
      selectInput("Y_variable", " Y Variable:", 
                  c("No of Cylinders" = "Cylinders",
                    "Type of car" = "Type",
                    "Engine Size" = "EngineSize",
                    "Fuel Tank capacity" = "Fuel.tank.capacity",
                    "Origin of the car"="Origin",
                    "Prices"="Price",
                    "Rev /min"="RPM",
                    "Weight of car"="Weight",
                    "MPG city"="MPG.city",
                    "Horsepower of car"="HorsePower",
                    "Passengers capacity"="Passengers",
                    "Length of car"="Length",
                    "Manufacturer of car"="Manufacturer",
                    "Model of car"="Model" )),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                  
      tabPanel("Plots",
        plotOutput("main_plot")),  

      )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  data <- df
  
  
  data$Model <- factor(data$Model)
  data$Manufacturer <- factor(data$Manufacturer)
  data$Origin <- factor(data$Origin)
data2 <- data.frame(data)
  
  choices <- c("No of Cylinders" = "Cylinders",
               "Type of car" = "Type",
               "Engine Size" = "EngineSize",
               "Fuel Tank capacity" = "Fuel.tank.capacity",
               "Origin of the car"="Origin",
               "Prices"="Price",
               "Rev /min"="RPM",
               "Weight of car"="Weight",
               "MPG city"="MPG.city",
               "Horsepower of car"="HorsePower",
               "Passengers capacity"="Passengers",
               "Length of car"="Length",
               "Manufacturer of car"="Manufacturer",
               "Model of car"="Model" )

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    if(is.numeric(input$X_variable) & (is.numeric(input$Y_variable))){
    ggplot(data2, aes(x = data2[,input$X_variable], 
                      y=data2[,input$Y_variable])) + 
        geom_point(aes(shape = input$Y_variable,
                       color=input$Y_variable,size=input$Y_variable))  
    else if ((is.factor(input$X_variable) & 
              is.numeric(input$Y_variable)) | 
             (is.factor(input$Y_variable) & 
              is.numeric(input$X_variable))){   
      ggplot(data2, aes(x = data2[,input$X_variable], 
                     y=data2[,input$Y_variable])) +
        geom_boxplot(aes(shape = input$Y_variable,
                         color=input$Y_variable,size=input$Y_variable))  
  } 
 else { ggplot(data2, aes(data2[,input$X_variable])) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill=input$X_variable)) 
    }
    })
  

  


})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It is only working fine for `else` part but not for `if` and `else if` part. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `df  <- read_table("cars.xls")`.  We don't have access to your Excel spreadsheet.  So your code is not reproducible.  Nor is it minimal.  Can you be more specific than It is only working fine foe [sic] else part but not for if and else if part"?  Do you get any error messages?  if so, what are they?  if you get output, why does it not meet your needs?

Comment: I have uploaded the excl sheet on this link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VeH6_SL5VLxykIFgOPXopaOEDdBu6ytPrphP0Iibmrk/edit?usp=sharing. I am only getting barplot even if I change the variables to factors. No errors shown in console. From if else i mean in the three if, else if and else only the else part is giving me output. I guess I have some error in conditions for if statement. 3 columns are characters while all others are numerical columns in dataset. 3 characters columns are converted to factors in the code if u look just below `server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df  <- read_xlsx("cars.xlsx")

choices <- c("No of Cylinders" = "Cylinders",
             "Type of car" = "Type",
             "Engine Size" = "EngineSize",
             "Fuel Tank capacity" = "Fuel.tank.capacity",
             "Origin of the car"="Origin",
             "Prices"="Price",
             "Rev /min"="RPM",
             "Weight of car"="Weight",
             "MPG city"="MPG.city",
             "Horsepower of car"="HorsePower",
             "Passengers capacity"="Passengers",
             "Length of car"="Length",
             "Manufacturer of car"="Manufacturer",
             "Model of car"="Model" )

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Car Dataset Analysis"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("X_variable", "X Variable:", choices = choices),
      selectInput("Y_variable", " Y Variable:", choices = choices)
    ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
                    tabPanel("Plots", plotOutput("main_plot")),  
                    
        )
      )
    )
))
  
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    data <- df
    
    data$Model <- factor(data$Model)
    data$Manufacturer <- factor(data$Manufacturer)
    data$Origin <- factor(data$Origin)
    data2 <- data.frame(data)
    
    output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
      x <- data2[[input$X_variable]]
      y <- data2[[input$Y_variable]]
      if(is.numeric(x) & (is.numeric(y))){
        ggplot(data2, aes(x = .data[[input$X_variable]], y=.data[[input$Y_variable]])) + 
          geom_point(aes(shape = input$Y_variable, color=input$Y_variable, size=input$Y_variable))  
        }else if ((is.factor(x) & is.numeric(y)) | (is.factor(y) & is.numeric(x))) {
          ggplot(data2, aes(x = .data[[input$X_variable]], y=.data[[input$Y_variable]])) +
            geom_boxplot(aes(shape = input$Y_variable, color=input$Y_variable, size=input$Y_variable))  
        } 
        else {
          ggplot(data2, aes(.data[[input$X_variable]])) + geom_bar(aes(fill=input$X_variable)) 
        }
      })
    
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```